# Trying to plot a CSV file and getting a blank graph

Tags: plotting, csv-format

I am trying to plot two NMR line graphs superimposed to show a before and after. I was able to successfully do it with excel files but the CSV files have been giving me trouble. This is my code. I tested the two import lines and it spits out a series of ordered pairs however the x and y values are not separated by commas.

```
 0911PECHGBISO = Import["/Users/Desktop/Lab Stuff/0911\Data/0911-PECH-GB-ISO2.csv",{"Data", ;; , ;;}];
0911PECHGB = Import["/Users/Desktop/Lab Stuff/0911\Data/0911-PECH-GB.csv", {"Data", ;; , ;;}];

ListLinePlot[{0911PECHGBISO, 0911PECHGB}, 



Frame ->  {{False, False}, {True, False}},
 PlotRange -> {{3, 5.5}, {-10000, 200000}}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", "Linear"}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Chemical Shift (ppm)"}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Blue, Thickness[0.001]], 
   Directive[Black, Thickness[0.001]]}, ImageSize -> Large, 
 LabelStyle -> {Black, FontSize -> 22}, FrameStyle -> Black, 
 AspectRatio -> 0.618, GridLines -> {{}, {0, 1.618}},
 PlotLegends -> 
  LineLegend[{Blue, Black}, {"After TCI", "Before TCI"}], 
 FrameTicks -> {{None, 
    None}, {LinTicks[3, 5.5, 1, 4, TickDirection -> Out, 
     DecimalDigits -> 1, TickLengthScale -> 3], None}}]
```

My output for one of the files is
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, no one is going to able to see any of your actual data because it's on your hard drive, and hidden inside the symbols you've defined. In general, if you don't get a plot, it's because what you're attempting to plot isn't a set of numeric quantities. To debug, try replacing plot with Table, and dump a few values out in the region of interest. The various options probably aren't a factor. If you want help, show a few values with Short or Take so users can see what your data looks like. Actually, if your data is returned as lists, you'll probably need to use something like

Comment: ..Transpose to convert the lists into a list of {x,y} pairs.

Comment: How would I go about transposing and not mess up the order of the list?

Comment: Are you saying that you have two lists, each of which is already a set of {{x1,y1},{x2,y2},...} pairs? If you plot just one at a time, do you get a valid plot? If so, then you just need to Join the lists together into one. Use Join[list1,list2] inside your plot function. I assumed the first was a list of x values, and the second a list of y values; for this case, you need to transpose, but not if they are already a set of x,y pairs.

Comment: ah no I have two CSV files each with a unique set of {x,y} values however it uploads as {x1 y1}, {x2 y2} instead of it being {x1, y1}, {x2,y2}. Does that make sense?

Comment: Are you saying the data are separated numbers without commas between them? If so, as soon as you Import, they'll be converted into x*y products since a blank space is interpreted as multiplication in Mathematica. But then why does your Short above show unevaluated pairs? If you do First@0911PECHGB //FullForm, what does the output look like? What you need is to get your data to look like {{-3.59471, 17.7381},...}, with a comma separating the two numbers, either during the Import, or after. Or is it just a problem with uploading to this web site?

Comment: Hey! my output looks like this List["-3.59471\t17.7381"] , I'm super new to this so I am struggling figuring out the form changes, I really appreciate all of your help on this @jdp

Comment: That's a string with a tab character in it. Could you upload a sample of the CSV file so people can assist with the importing?

Comment: Try running this function on each of your two 0911.. files, assigning the output to new varaibles (d1/d2 in my example), and retry the plot with d1,d2. toNumber[data_] := ToExpression /@ Flatten[StringSplit /@ data, 1]; The function splits the string at the tab character backslash-t, (considered whitespace) Flatten[..,1] removes the extra list bracket, and ToExpression gets mapped over the strings to convert everything to a list of lists each containing a pair of numbers. I.e. d1 = toNumber[ 0911PECHGBISO], d2 = toNumber[0911PECHGB].

Comment: @jdp what does the [data_] mean? should I be calling d1 and d2 specifically?

Comment: When you define a function, the lhs normally contains one or more "patterns". The arguments you pass in when you call the function bind to the pattern, and the arguments appear on the rhs which executes the code. So if you put your symbol name inside toNumber[yourdata], yourdata replaces the "data" in the rhs of the definition. The output gets assigned to the new symbols; in my example, I used d1/d2 for the two symbols you were using. So change the code in your plot to use d1,d2 instead of the 0911... variables your originally used. The names you choose are completely arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something, but there is a glaring problem in your code:

```
0911PECHGBISO = Import[...]
```

An identifier cannot start with a number. You have essentially written

```
Times[0911, PECHGBISO] = Import[...]
```

I assume you have gotten an error message saying:

```
Tag Times in 0911 PECHGBISO is Protected.
```

And nothing has been set. This is apparent in your screenshot: In `Short[0911PECHGB]`, the word `PECHGB` appear in blue. It's a symbol that's unknown to Mathematica, it hasn't been set to anything.

Comment: Yeah so fair sorry, it started with my initials which I removed for security purposes